# How to set dbus/systemd as dependency in systemd unit

Tags: go, systemd, dbus, autostart

I have a small program written in `Go` which uses the [go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd) library to interact with systemd using dbus.

The program itself is registered as a systemd unit and shall start upon boot. When the program is running, it will regularly query systemd unit status for several units.

Now when I manually start the program, everything is fine. However, when started after reboot by systemd, it will "hang", means it will be unable to query systemd unit status via dbus. I will get the following message from the `go-systemd` library:

```
Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Now when I just restart my program, it will immediately be able to query systemd units without error. This leads me to the assumption of wrong/misconfigured dependencies for my program, so that upon boot there will be a race condition which leads to the program being unable to communicate with systemd over dbus.

Now I have already put this, and several other combinations, however it does not help:

```
Requires=dbus.service
After=dbus.service
Wants=org.freedesktop.systemd1
```

How do I need to configure my own systemd unit (of the go-program) in order for it to be able to communicate with systemd over dbus right after reboot? What dependency do I have to configure?

Comment: Agreed that it sounds like your program is starting before all the dependencies have started. Is your program trying to restart when it fails? Not ideal but you could try `Restart=always` and `RestartSec=5s` in your configuration to see if it does start eventually. The following blog has some useful information around starting services: https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/

Comment: Well, the program _starts_, its up, systemd shows green for my program, everything well. It just cannot reach dbus/systemd. I doubt putting restart-policies will change that, because it does not crash/stop/restart.

I could, of course, make the program crash in case dbus/systemd is not reachable, to force a restart, however this sounds like a pretty suboptimal solution to me.

Comment: Agreed it is a suboptimal solution. It was purely an experiment to see if it started eventually. I guess I misunderstood your `exited with status 1` you had in your question.

Comment: Are you connecting to the session bus instead of the system bus?  The session bus doesn't exist if your program is started with systemd.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I am using `dbus.NewUserConnectionContext(ctx)`, which opens a connection to the user instance of systemd. And it might not yet exist yet, but it will be started when I log into the machine using SSH, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your program is trying to connect to the DBus Session bus by default, since you say it works fine when you run it manually.  When an application starts up from Systemd, it will by default running as root with no session bus to connect to, so it will fail.

The session bus is generally started on a per-login basis when a user logs in on a graphical terminal.  It does not start by default when logging in on a terminal.

If this is the case, you have two options that I can see at the moment:

1. Use the system bus instead of the session bus.
2. Create your own bus that you connect to, different from the session bus and the system bus.  The simplest way is to use `dbus-launch` to create a new bus that your application can connect to.